# Determine if a coordinate reference system is projected from Proj text

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, epsg

I'm looking for a reliable way to determine if a coordinate reference system is projected or not based on its Proj text.

As examples I'm looking at [EPSG:3857](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/epsg3857-wgs84-web-mercator-auxiliary-sphere/proj4/) and [EPSG:4326](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/proj4/)

EPSG:3857: `+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs`

EPSG:4326: `+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`

Is there a rule I can apply across all Proj-supported coordinate reference systems? For example: any value that is not `longlat` in `+proj=` will be projected.